# Android Options Menu Without ActionBar?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

what I'm looking for is to make an options menu but without the ActionBar. In the Google music app I saw that they have a options menu sort of thing with no action bar. Below is a picture of what I was talking about in the Google music app.

Thank you in advance! :)
[image: googleplaymusicapp]

Comment: Other than height, that would appear to be an action bar and its overflow. You are welcome to use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to perhaps better determine what it is.

Comment: Looks like an action bar to me??

Comment: @CommonsWare I was unaware actionbar could be used that way. Could you check out the edited image, surely that's not an actionbar too?

Comment: If this is running on a device configured for an RTL language, that could be the standard split action bar, as the overflow should be at the end (which, in an RTL language, is on the right). Otherwise, this is probably some custom bar set up to look like the standard split action bar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's just a simple popop.  You can do that on any view.  Throw an icon on a view, like the overflow menu icone and set a click listener on it.

This example is a list of devices (smartphones) in a catalog. I populate the tag with an object so I know which one the user clicks on.

```
public void showDeviceMenu(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    popup.inflate(R.menu.cart_device_menu);
    DeviceTag tag = (DeviceTag) v.getTag();
    final String groupId = tag.groupId;
    final String sku = tag.sku;
    final String productId = tag.productId;
    SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder(tag.name);

    text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, text.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_name).setTitle(text);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.duplicate_device:
                    duplicateDevice(sku, productId);
                    return true;
                case R.id.update_device:
                    updateWirelessItemInCart(sku,groupId);
                    return true;
                case R.id.delete_device:
                    removeItemFromCart(groupId);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
           }
        }

    });
    popup.show();
}
```